# credentials for CloudStorageAccount using DevelopmentStorage

Tags: azure, c#-4.0, cloud-storage

I'm developing a webjob to put items in a queue (C#).  I'm new to this and I'm following some tutorials, but I can't figure out how I would create an instance of a `CloudStorageAccount` for my local development storage.  In my config file, I have this

```html
<add name="AzureWebJobsStorage" connectionString="UseDevelopmentStorage=true;" />
```

and In my C# method, I want to create an instance of my `CloudStorageAccount`, like this

```
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
```

what should `accountName` and `accountKey` be for local development storage?

Answer (score 7):

> what should accountName and accountKey be for local development
>   storage ?

```
Account name: devstoreaccount1
Account key: Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-emulator

However you will not be able to use the code below as storage emulator only works on HTTP and listens on custom ports.

```
var account = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
```

Correct way to do would be to something like below:

```
        var storageCredentials = new StorageCredentials("devstoreaccount1", "Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==");
        var blobEndpoint = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10000");
        var queueEndpoint = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10001");
        var tableEndpoint = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:10002");
        var acc = new CloudStorageAccount(storageCredentials, blobEndpoint, queueEndpoint, tableEndpoint, null);
```

or for simplicity, you could simply do:

```
        var acc = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");
```

Comment: I got it working ok using CloudStorageAccount.Parse("UseDevelopmentStorage=true");  Eveything was working fine until i updated Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage to V8.2.1.0  Im now getting this error  Invalid storage account 'devstoreaccount1'. Please make sure your credentials are correct. is this a known issue ?

Comment: For other users with the same problem, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45370503/microsoft-windowsazure-storage-update-to-v8-2-1-0-has-broken-my-code.

Comment: @KristofferJälén refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/48658275/6527049