# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage update to V8.2.1.0 has broken my code

Tags: c#, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues

I've created a WebJob that places items in a queue, this process worked perfectly well until I updated **Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage** to **v8.2.1.0** and I'm now getting this error

> 'Invalid storage account 'devstoreaccount1'. Please make sure your
>   credentials are correct.'

It was working perfectly well until the update, is this an issue? whats the fix?

Comment: reverted back to V7.2.1.0 and everything works fine again, does anyone know what the problem is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [article](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net#use-with-the-azure-storage-emulator), you could find:

> The Client Library uses a particular Storage Service version. In order to use the Storage Client Library with the Storage Emulator, a corresponding minimum version of the Azure Storage Emulator must be used. Older versions of the Storage Emulator do not have the necessary code to successfully respond to new requests.
>   Currently, the minimum version of the Azure Storage Emulator needed for this library is 5.4. If you encounter a VersionNotSupportedByEmulator (400 Bad Request) error, please update the [Storage Emulator](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/).

But I have also downloaded the Storage Emulator from this page. The Storage Emulator version currently is 5.1.

So I suggest you could firstly create a feed at this [site](https://feedback.azure.com/) and wait for the storage emulator team update the version.

Currently, if you want to use Storage Emulator to test, I suggest you could use the version below 8.2.0.

[The storage SKD release notes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/changelog.txt).

Comment: I'm sticking with V7.2.1.0 for the time being, it seems to work ok

Comment: Yes, because the newest storage SDK use the 2017-04-17 REST version. But the emulator 5.1 doesn't support this 2017-04-17 REST version. So you couldn't use it now. You could wait the new version of the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Although [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45408864/6527049) above works fine, But still you are facing the same error. You can follow the below steps, it's working in my case.

You have to make sure that [Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) is started, start it if not started.

[image: Azure Storage Emulator status]

If this also doesn't work then follow the below steps:

1. Run command prompt as admin.
2. Run `cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\Storage
   Emulator>`.
3. Run `AzureStorageEmulator.exe init`.
4. Run `AzureStorageEmulator.exe start`.